# Why won't it tear? Trying to write an example program showing tearing for long between two threads in java

Tags: java, concurrency

According to the java standard longs are written in two parts, and it is possible in one thread to read a number that was never written b/c it consists of the first part of one write and the second of another (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.7).  I have tried to write a program that shows this happening; but it never happens.  Do I misunderstand the standard, or is there an error in my example program.

In the program below if tearing happens, we should get an output

```
[main] INFO net.kasterma.basicjava.TearingTest2 - compare false
```

This has not happened in many runs.

```
package net.kasterma.basicjava;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Set;

@Slf4j
public class TearingTest2 extends Thread {
    private final boolean read;
    private static long i = 0;
    private final static int ITERATIONS = 1_000_000;
    private final static long[] read_i = new long[ITERATIONS];
    private final static long[] write_i = new long[ITERATIONS];
    private final static Random random = new Random();

    TearingTest2(boolean read) {
        this.read = read;
    }

    public void run() {
        if (read) {
            for (int iter = 0; iter < ITERATIONS; iter++) {
//                log.info("read {}", iter);
                read_i[iter] = i;
            }
        } else {
            for (int iter = 0; iter < ITERATIONS; iter++) {
//                log.info("write {}", iter);
                i = random.nextLong();
                write_i[iter] = i;
            }
        }
    }

    static boolean compare() {
        Set<Long> writes = new HashSet<>();
        writes.add(0L);
        Arrays.stream(write_i).forEach(l -> writes.add(l));
        for (int iter = 0; iter < ITERATIONS; iter++) {
            if (!writes.contains(read_i[iter])) {
                log.info("not found {}", iter);
                return false;  // <--- tearing has happened.
            }
        }

        // compute some statistics for debugging of the program
        Set<Long> reads = new HashSet<>();
        Arrays.stream(read_i).forEach(l -> reads.add(l));
        log.info("Number of read values {}", reads.size());
        int ct = 0;
        for (int iter = 0; iter < ITERATIONS; iter++) {
            if (read_i[iter] == 0) {
                ct++;
            }
        }
        log.info("number zeros {}", ct);
        return true;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread T1 = new TearingTest2(true);
        Thread T2 = new TearingTest2(false);
        T1.start();
        T2.start();
        T1.join();
        T2.join();
        log.info("compare {}", compare());
    }
}
```

The output of a run is:

```
[main] INFO net.kasterma.basicjava.TearingTest2 - Number of read values 105328
[main] INFO net.kasterma.basicjava.TearingTest2 - number zeros 1575
[main] INFO net.kasterma.basicjava.TearingTest2 - compare true
```

Comment: `Random` is thread-safe, so it might cause a side-effect of more memory consistency. You could try generating an array of numbers first before actually starting the threads, then just copying the numbers out of the array.

Comment: Unfortunately moving the random number generation into the constructor doesn't make a difference.  I.e create the write_i array with random in the constructor, and have i = write_i[iter] in the writing loop

Comment: Well, I wouldn't be surprised if this particular effect was hard to observe. Another thing you could try is running with -Xint to disable HotSpot. HotSpot can do some pretty aggressive optimizations around non-volatile variables. (It would e.g. be legal for HotSpot to optimize your reader code to do something equivalent to `Arrays.fill(read_i, 0)` because there's no guarantee that reads of `i` will see anything past the initial value.)

Comment: I have added the output of a run to show that at least nothing quite that straightforward happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the same article regarding standard that you've mentioned

> Some implementations may find it convenient to divide a single write action on a 64-bit long or double value into two write actions on adjacent 32-bit values. For efficiency's sake, this behavior is implementation-specific; an **implementation of the Java Virtual Machine is free to perform writes to long and double values atomically or in two parts**.
>
> Implementations of the Java Virtual Machine **are encouraged to avoid splitting** 64-bit values where possible.

So I think for some JVMs you may never see such split because of how JVM is implemented